# Odoo10 - How to remove the module name in form view ? (Refer below picture)

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

[image: See here]

How to remove the module name in number 1 and change it to other default name plus the id like So015 in sale order in odoo 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, it is a missing field **name** in your action definition.

```xml
<field name="name">Custom Shipping</field>
```

so you have to make sure that your action for such model is as following:

```xml
<!-- ACTION WINDOW FOR CUSTOM_SHIPPING.MODELS -->
<record id="action_custom_shipping_models" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Custom Shipping</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">custom_shipping.models</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!-- ACTION WINDOW FOR CUSTOM_SHIPPING.MODELS -->
```

to solve the second problem you may need the following definitions

```
class custom_shipping(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom_shipping.models'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    _rec_name = 'sr_no'

    sr_no = fields.Char(string='Project Name', default='New' ,required=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('sr_no', 'New') == 'New':
            vals['sr_no'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('custom_shipping.number') or '/'
    return super(custom_shipping, self).create(vals)
```

in addition to this xml

```
<!-- SEQUENCE FOR CUSTOM_SHIPPNIG.MODELS -->
<record id="seq_custom_shipping_models" model="ir.sequence">
  <field name="name">Custom Shipping Number</field>
  <field name="code">custom_shipping.number</field>
  <field name="prefix">SO</field>
  <field name="padding">5</field>
  <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
</record>
<!-- SEQUENCE FOR CUSTOM_SHIPPNIG.MODELS -->
```

Comment: hello  kerbrose i trying your solution but its not work with me maybe i do something wrong i really don't know and sorry for late

Comment: i want to add one more thing i remove order line from my module does it what make the problem , and my full apologize if my language is bad

Comment: could you please provide us with you python code & the definition of the action which will be in a file .xml

Comment: ok here my code for name :
class custom_shipping(models.Model):
 _name = 'custom_shipping.models'
 _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
 _rec_name = 'sr_no'

 sr_no = fields.Char(string='Project Name', unique = True,required=True) 
 # name = fields.Char(string='Shipp Reference', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, index=True)
 # default=lambda self: _('New')

Comment: my view : 
        <div class="oe_title">
            <h1>
                <field name="sr_no" readonly="1"/>
            </h1>
        </div>

Comment: the action i used the one you send to me in your comment

Comment: one more thing please do you know the way to linked this module to accounts

Comment: what do you mean?? I need more explanation. you can also make a new question to be related to the subject & put more details. don't forget to mention me there

Comment: my new question link is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030360/how-to-linking-my-custom-module-to-accounting

Answer (score 0):

There are two chances for this issue:

1. The "name" field is left empty or
2. There is not "name" field in the form.

Solutions:

1. Declare a field named "name" or
2. Use "_rec_name" to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    _name = 'reg.project'

    name = fields.Char(string='Project Name', unique = True, required=True)
```

Or this code :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    _name = 'reg.project'
    _rec_name = 'sr_no'

    sr_no = fields.Char(string='Project Name', unique = True, required=True)
```

Comment: the two solutions changed the old name by  False

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **"name"** field in your object and get your solution...